# How do I query the result of xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using xmlhttprequest, how do I query the result using jQuery?

E.g. I am running this code snippet:

```
$.get('somepage.htm', function(data) {
  console.log($("div.abc").text());
});
```

Of course $("div.abc").text() is applied to the current page, rather than the page contained in the data variable. How do I fix this and apply $("div.abc").text() to the content of data?

Comment: please elaborate. The question is not clear. What do you want to achieve exactly? What do you want to do with the received data from the ajax call?

Comment: I am fetching a web page and want to extract some text from it.

Comment: can you do `console.log(data);` and check the response first? is `data` a string? is it JSON? it all depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a jQuery object from the data.

```
var $data = $(data);
```

Then manipulate that:

```
console.log($data.find("div.abc").text())
```

Comment: Is there a speed advantage to defining var $data rather than using $(data) directly? (Assuming multiple jQueries.)

Comment: If you're going to query the data multiple times, then there is probably a speed advantage, but probably not a significant one. I did it this way because it shows what is happening more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

use the `.find()` method

```
 $(data).find("div.abc").text("text");
```